# I want to double the speed of master video clips while retaining the audio's original speed

Tags: video, premiere, adobe

In the field I accidentally recorded about 80 clips at 50% slo-motion and need to restore the video to normal motion.  Audio is recorded at the proper speed. Is there a way to do this, as a batch, in the media browser, rather than individually in the timeline? If I must do it in the timeline, can multiple clips be fixed at once? and then exported as individual clips back to the media browser?